# Absolutely convergent series given other sequence converge

Tags: real-analysis

If the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ is convergent and if the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n$ is absolutely convergent, does this imply that $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}y_{n}$ converges absolutely?

Comment: By product do you mean the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x_ny_n}$?

Comment: The next one that is direct and not cauchy.

Comment: Please format your question and specify the product meant.

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means. This needs rewriting.

Comment: I am talking about this series. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x_ny_n}$ does it converges absolutely?

Comment: Hint:  we know that, for large enough $n$, $|x_n|<1$.

Comment: Hint: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n y_n| \leq \sup_{k}|x_k| \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|$

Answer (score 0):

The series $\sum x_n$ converges, so
$ x_n$ goes to zero when $n$ tends to $+\infty$.
thus it becomes smaller and smaller,
and for great enough $n$ , we will have

$|x_n|<1$ for example.

so

$|x_n.y_n|\leq|y_n|$

the series $\sum |y_n|$  is convergent, thus the series $\sum |x_n.y_n|$ is also convergent. Qed.